# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - volume slider not working

Tags: 22.04, intel, volume-control

volume slider does not work. I hear the audio and I can modify it from the volume control of the specific app (for example, the slider of YT videos or spotify and so on), but when I use the key in my keyboard or the system slider in the control center it does not change: I have audio or I have not (when the slider is at zero). Basically I can just max out or turn off the volume, no steps in between. Anyone can help me?
I have an intel i7-13700h processor, Lenovo Yoga laptop.